# Who are the characters in the opening montage?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones-2015

In *Jessica Jones*, there’s a montage featuring shadowy images of people who are (presumably) characters from the show. For instance, these two people (having an argument?):

[image: Jessica Jones opening sequence, shadowy figures in a window]

There are others, of course. Unfortunately, the images are too dark for me to identify.

Who are the people who appear in this opening montage? Do they contain clues to the events in the show, or are they perhaps even unrelated? And do they change between seasons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having watched all of Season 1 and the majority of Season 2 so far, I can't think of any characters in the show that would line up with the silhouettes in the opening credits sequence. The sequence is also identical between seasons, though only about half of the characters are the same.

The montage just seems to be a sequence of random people in New York, designed to invoke the feeling of a private investigator. The people are all being watched or followed surreptitiously, the way Jessica would do in her "day job".